# symbol's function definition is void: slime-face-inheritance-possible-p

Tags: slime

When I try to start Emacs I get the following warning:

```
symbol's function definition is void: slime-face-inheritance-possible-p
```

This happens most of the time, only sometimes it seems to work. If I remove all installed packages (`package.el`) and install them again, then it works fine on the first start, but not on subsequent starts.

I'm using the packages `slime`, `slime-repl` and `slime-company`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [commit 2e5538a](https://github.com/slime/slime/commit/2e5538a59881d4767ea4773f1bf7efa9299a2e3a) the long deprecated function `slime-face-inheritance-possible-p` has been removed from `slime` in May 2015.

You probably installed the package `slime-repl` via marmalade, where it is currently listed as version `20100404`, e.g. being from 2010 and thus very old.

As of now (October 2015) the package `slime` also contains the `slime-repl.el` in the `contrib` folder, and thus supports the slime-repl out of the box (after enabling it via `slime-contribs`). To solve the issue just remove the obsolete package `slime-repl`.